# Creating HTTPS login on iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, authentication, operating-system

How do I build an https login on iOS? (Like this one: https://info.tam.ch/kks)

I only know how to solve a .htaccess.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I use [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) in my iPhone project to communicate with the web application. For http authentication, they have a convenient ASIAuthenticationDialog class that takes care of that. Basic usage is as follows:

```
// Specifying a username and password to use in the URL
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://username:password@allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];

// Setting a username and password to use on the request
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://allseeing-i.com/top_secret/"];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setUsername:@"username"];
[request setPassword:@"password"];
```

You can visit [here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use) for detailed information or check out the sample source code [here](https://github.com/pokeb/asi-http-request/tree) on github.